# Bhatia, Ex 7.1.12: Principal angles between subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

I am unable to solve this problem in Matrix Analysis by Rajendra Bhatia: [image]

I can't see how to prove that $\theta_i$ are decreasing. I also have no intuition for why the angles are defined this way. Online search show that one can also define angles using [just min (instead of max-min)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats#Variational_characterization). I would appreciate some intuition into these as well as a solution sketch to the above problem.

Comment: Note that the definition you linked uses just a **min** (rather than just a max). The resulting angles satisfy $\theta_1 \leq \cdots \leq \theta_m$, contrary to Bhatia's convention

Comment: Also, note that the exercise is not actually asking you to show that these angles are decreasing

Comment: Yes, I see that but I tried to and failed, so I'd like to see how that is proven too

Comment: Regarding intuition: for a given vector $x$, $\min_{y \in \mathcal F} \angle (x,y)$ is the angle between $x$ and the subspace $\mathcal F$. That is, you can think of this as $\angle(x, \mathcal F)$. With that established, the first principal angle is simply $\max_{x \in \mathcal E} \angle (x,\mathcal F)$.